# Two borders overlapping with different sizes

Tags: html, css

Is there any better way of setting two borders like in the example below? I could only do it with positioning. I'm new here so I apologize for any mistakes whatsoever.

```css
.border1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 9px solid red;
  position: relative;  
}

.border2 {
  border: 9px solid blue;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: -33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border1">
  <div class="border2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolute is indeed a good and easy way here.

You can also use a pseudo and only coordonates to size the second border box.

```css
.border1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 150px;/* allow it to grow */
  width: 250px;
  padding:20px 0.5em;
  border: 9px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.border2:before {
content:'';
  border: 9px solid blue;
pointer-events:none;/* to allow clicking through else you may use a negative z-index */
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
bottom:12px;
  left: -33px;
right:-33px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border1 border2">
add anything here instead setting height
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** and without unnecessary calculations:

```css
.border1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 9px solid red;
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  justify-content: center; /* centers them horizontally */
  align-items: center; /* and vertically */
}
  
.border2 {
  flex: 0 0 300px; /* doesn't shrink, flex-basis set to "300px" (initial width) */
  border: 9px solid blue;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="border1">
  <div class="border2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach. I used box-shadow as the second border and you will no longer need a second div for second border.

```css
.border{
   margin:0 auto;
   height:300px;
   width:250px;
   border:9px solid red;
   position:relative; 
   box-shadow: 0 0 0px 9px blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Comment: This is not like the shape that is asked for.